# What Happens to the JVM When a Computer is Put to Sleep?

Tags: java, performance, networking, jvm, sleep

I was always curious what happens to the JVM when the computer is put to sleep. Are network connections interrupted? What happens to the JVM when the computer sleeps, and how can it affect a programming executing on the JVM?

Comment: The JVM is a process just like any other. It gets suspended along with the rest of them.  The networking behavior depends on the platform and the specifics of the application. Java programs executing on the VM will not be able to respond to any incoming communication.

Comment: @Archa5238: Consider adding that as an answer, both for the benefit of future readers (comments are ephemeral, answers are mostly permanent) and so this question doesn't appear unanswered.